# How to form state space tree in a 2 player game same as billiards with alternate game turns

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am trying to solve [carrom](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrom) board game ( Same as billiard game ) using AI techniques by forming a search tree. Since my game rule not giving strike turn again even after pocketing, my state space tree will have only depth 1 with all the possible shots as branches to root. What is the best approach to solve this kind of problems in AI to chose the best shot.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple [minimax algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax). You expand the search tree from your opponents view iteratively and calculate a score for the states. Your opponent is trying to minimize the score (which is best for him), you try to maximize the score and choose the action that leads to the tree with the best score.